# Getting an arrow function syntax error in React

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, arrow-functions, setstate

I have following code which is rendering the React app.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list'

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCF7K58Xwpr7m5C0yGy8Bck02iQ0fJ2yuI';


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = {videos: []};

    this.YTSearch = this.YTSearch.bind(this);
  }

  YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: BMW}, (videos => {
    this.setState({ videos });
  });
);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoList videos={ this.state.videos }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Also I think I have some syntax problem with using the setState function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class` body is for defining functions and variables but you are calling the function `YTSearch` inside class body, which is giving syntax error. If you want to call the function then either call it inside constructor or inside any other function like componentDidMount etc

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {videos: []};
  }

componentDidMount(){
   // Call it here inside componentDidMount or any other function
    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: BMW}, (videos => {
      this.setState({ videos });
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Prakash Sharma. I got what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your destructured setState is fine, you have a bracket `(`open which needs to be closed or either way you can remove it as there is only one argument in your arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific issue isn't made clear in your question but from looking at your code I assume your YTSearch is never firing and therefore your state never gets set with a list of videos.

If you are trying to create a method to pass to the search bar that triggers a search perhaps try something like this.  I hope this helps!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCF7K58Xwpr7m5C0yGy8Bck02iQ0fJ2yuI';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { videos: [] };

    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  search(phrase) {
    YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: phrase }, videos => {
      this.setState({ videos });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.search}/>
        <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```